# heroku permanently delete the account with terminal

Tags: heroku, terminal

I would remove the heroku login with the terminal so I use the command:

`heroku accounts: remove mylogin`

but he told me: `That account is the current account, set Reviews another account first.`

How to remove the login?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to `~/.heroku/accounts` and remove the files in their that correspond to the account you want to remove.